# Pretty circles connecting nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know how to get pretty curves with the tikz edges. I don't quite understand the semanthic of the degrees bending. With the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds, fit, calc, positioning}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,draw=black]
\tikzstyle{fixed}=[-,dotted, shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',very thin]
\tikzstyle{followed}=[-,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',thick]

\node[vertex] (v0) {$v_0$};
\node[vertex] (v1) [right of = v0] {$v_1$};
\node[vertex] (v2) [right of = v1] {$v_2$};

\path
    (v0) edge [followed] node[above, very near start] () {$2$} (v1)
    (v1) edge [followed] node[above, very near start] (v1derecha) {} node[above, very near end] (v2izquierda) {$4$} (v2);

\node [above = 0cm of v1] (v1content) {$6$};
\node [right = 0cm of v2] (v2content) {$2$};

\path
    (v1derecha.north) edge [->, bend right= 45] (v1content.east) {}
    (v2content.north) edge [->, bend right= 45] (v2izquierda.north) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get the following picture:

[image: First try]

Or if I change it to 90:

[image: Second try]

So I think the angle is the incoming angle in respect to the pointed point(?). In any case, do I I get a full circle rather than a squashed one?

Comment: The curve will probably look nice if it is circular and concentric with your node circles. Try using an `arc` instead of `bend`. `\draw [->, thick] (v1derecha.north) arc (10:90:0.4);
\draw [->, thick] (v2content.north) arc (10:150:0.6);` The above code is trial and error though.

Comment: Along with `arc`, as suggested by @AJN, also `\usetikzlibrary{bending}` to make sure the shape of the arrow doesn't distort the arc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright thanks to AJN and smike I ended up doing something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds, fit, calc, positioning, bending}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,draw=black]
\tikzstyle{followed}=[-,thick]

\node[vertex] (v0) {$v_0$};
\node[vertex] (v1) [right of = v0] {$v_1$};
\node[vertex] (v2) [right of = v1] {$v_2$};

\path
    (v0) edge [followed] node[above, very near start] () {$2$} (v1)
    (v1) edge [followed] node[above, very near start] (v1derecha) {} node[above, very near end] (v2izquierda) {$4$} (v2);

\node [above = 0cm of v1] (v1content) {$6$};
\node [right = 0cm of v2] (v2content) {$2$};

\path   (v1derecha.north) edge [->, bend right= 45] (v1content.east) {};
\draw[->]   (v2content.north) arc [start angle = 10, end angle = 140, radius = 0.65cm];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's a bit unfortunate can't done with an edge but the end result is fairly good.